# ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match ... Only on ONE user has issues

Tags: xss, http-status-code-403, mod-security

Not the first one with ModSecurity: `Access denied with code 403 (phase 2)....` issues.

But the thing is, I have a server, multiple websites, multiple webmail users and nobody is having any issues. There is this one user that keeps having issues sending email via webmail.

The full error is:

```
[client 86.xx.xxx.xxx] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). 
Pattern match "(?i)((?:\\\\bx(?:link:href|html|mlns)|!ENTITY\\\\b.*?
\\\\b(?:SYSTEM|PUBLIC)|\\\\bdata:text\\\\/html))" at ARGS:Parameters. 
[file "/etc/apache2/modsecurity.d/rules/comodo_free/07_XSS_XSS.conf"]
[line "173"] [id "213060"] [rev "5"] [msg "COMODO WAF: XSS Filter - 
Category 3: Attribute Vector||mail.mywebsite.nl|F|2"] [severity "CRITICAL"]
[tag "CWAF"] [tag "XSS"] [hostname "mail.mywebsite.nl"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "ZJqH1d8z978UF9Ye1LgFlwAAAEw"],
referer: https://mail.mywebsite.nl/
```

I've whitelisted his (dynamic) IP address(es) multiple times, and then he can send some mail, up until his new dynamic email address is blacklisted once again.

Since it is referring to XSS, (which I hardly have any experience with), could it be that he has a faulty browser plugin for example that my server is blocking? Any thoughts on how to fix this on my side OR to tell him that it might be his fault? Non of the other users (and I really have plenty!) are facing any issues via webmail!

So, I'm not sure if this is a server issue or that this specific user has some issues on his computer...

[edit]
ID 213060 gives the following:

```
SecRule REQUEST_COOKIES|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/__utm/|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/_pk_ref/|REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES|REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent|ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|XML:/*|!ARGS:/body/|!ARGS:/content/|!ARGS:/description/|!ARGS:Post|!ARGS:desc|!ARGS:html_message|!ARGS:text|!ARGS:/jform\[params\]\[offcanvas_topmod_style\]/|!ARGS:/jform\[params\]\[djmegamenu-module_style\]/|!ARGS:/jform\[params\]\[offcanvas_botmod_style\]/ "@rx (?i)((?:\bx(?:link:href|html|mlns)|!ENTITY\b.*?\b(?:SYSTEM|PUBLIC)|\bdata:text\/html))" \
        "id:213060,msg:'COMODO WAF: XSS Filter - Category 3: Attribute Vector||%{tx.domain}|%{tx.mode}|2',phase:2,deny,status:403,log,t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,t:htmlEntityDecode,t:removeNulls,t:removeComments,t:compressWhiteSpace,rev:5,severity:2,tag:'CWAF',tag:'XSS'"
```

[another edit:]

```
    --8f8b2a62-A--
    [27/Jun/2023:08:39:04.952346 +0200] ZJqECGcNX@kM-QmM3hU2ywAAABM 86.client ip 40330 85.server ip 7081
    --8f8b2a62-B--
    POST /?/Api/ HTTP/1.0
    Host: mail.mywebsite.nl
    X-Real-IP: 86.client ip
    Connection: close
    Content-Length: 8345
    sec-ch-ua: "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Microsoft Edge";v="114"
    x-deviceid: 04778820-c6fc-41c1-9d22-3e6f995c03bf
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    authorization: Bearer E1z-PplCaKTj68q73HG0bkSPgUCo_2KSStng_bk5JhGuF_IY5ctiCgm6NHBzru9XB7rvVwBDpBRndZp485pIijLk8pAd7ca5EvpGQF0p312jjCfvYcsy7yl3LDmHNWF5hGxK0PuUn5xOj4PRD7x0tnvlcOW-1IKInsitA5l4VCWTN04iFeQLG22gwRplcDfi-Kq33fwGDDP0yp7bYPq3vA0oyQv_9rWDQN3xF0MOasocYqA4VfIOd2wv31rxoTUj71gzuu6OELNfQSfTBbuUsE3K80I
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/114.0.1823.58
    content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
    x-client: WebClient
    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
    origin: https://mail.mywebsite.nl
    sec-fetch-site: same-origin
    sec-fetch-mode: cors
    sec-fetch-dest: empty
    referer: https://mail.mywebsite.nl/
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language: nl,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7
    cookie: AuthToken=E1z-PplCaKTj68q73HG0bkSPgUCo_2KSStng_bk5JhGuF_IY5ctiCgm6NHBzru9XB7rvVwBDpBRndZp485pIijLk8pAd7ca5EvpGQF0p312jjCfvYcsy7yl3LDmHNWF5hGxK0PuUn5xOj4PRD7x0tnvlcOW-1IKInsitA5l4VCWTN04iFeQLG22gwRplcDfi-Kq33fwGDDP0yp7bYPq3vA0oyQv_9rWDQN3xF0MOasocYqA4VfIOd2wv31rxoTUj71gzuu6OELNfQSfTBbuUsE3K80I; DeviceId=04778820-c6fc-41c1-9d22-3e6f995c03bf; aft-cache-ctrl=1
    
--554ba553-C--
Module=Mail&Method=SendMessage&Parameters=%7B%22AccountID%22%3A13%2C%22IdentityID%22%3A164%2C%22AliasID%22%3A%22%22%2C%22FetcherID%22%3A%22%22%2C%22DraftInfo%22%3A%5B%22reply%22%2C%22175%22%2C%22INBOX%22%5D%2C%22DraftUid%22%3A%22%22%2C%22To%22%3A%22user%40personalmail.nl%22%2C%22Cc%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Bcc%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Subject%22%3A%22RE%5B2%5D%3A+trainen%22%2C%22Text%22%3A%22%3Cdiv+data-crea%3D%5C%22font-wrapper%5C%22+style%3D%5C%22font-family%3A+Tahoma%2C+sans-serif%3B+font-size%3A+16px%3B+direction%3A+ltr%5C%22%3E%3Cdiv+style%3D%5C%22font-family%3A+Tahoma%3B+font-size%3A+16px%5C%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3Edag+Kees%2C%3Cdiv%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3EFijn+dat+het+trainen+je+bevalt.%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3EJe+afwezigheid+volgende+week+is+genoteerd.%26nbsp%3B+Bedankt+voor+het+tijdig+doorgeven.%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cdiv+data-crea%3D%5C%22font-wrapper%5C%22+style%3D%5C%22font-family%3A+Tahoma%2C+sans-serif%3B+font-size%3A+16px%3B+direction%3A+ltr%5C%22%3EMet+vriendelijke+groeten%2C%3Cdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3ECees+van+lastname%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3ECo%C3%B6rdinator+Sport+Overdag+ttv+MySportclub%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3Email%3A+faultyaddress%40mywebsite.nl%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E06-xxxxxxxx%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3Epriv%C3%A9+mail%3A+user%40personalmail.nl%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cfont+size%3D%5C%222%5C%22%3EAls+je+geen+mail+meer+wil+ontvangen+van+SportOverdag+van+ttv+MySportclub%2C+laat+me+dat+dan+even+weten.%3C%2Ffont%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cdiv+data-anchor%3D%5C%22reply-title%5C%22%3EOp+ma.%2C+jun.+26%2C+2023+om+14%3A28%2C+user%40personalmail.nl+schreef%3A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cblockquote%3E%3Cdiv+data-x-div-type%3D%5C%22html%5C%22+xmlns%3Av%3D%5C%22urn%3Aschemas-microsoft-com%3Avml%5C%22+xmlns%3Ao%3D%5C%22urn%3Aschemas-microsoft-com%3Aoffice%3Aoffice%5C%22+xmlns%3Aw%3D%5C%22urn%3Aschemas-microsoft-com%3Aoffice%3Aword%5C%22+xmlns%3Am%3D%5C%22http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.microsoft.com%2Foffice%2F2004%2F12%2Fomml%5C%22+xmlns%3D%5C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FTR%2FREC-html40%5C%22%3E%3Cdiv+data-x-div-type%3D%5C%22body%5C%22+lang%3D%5C%22NL%5C%22+link%3D%5C%22%230563C1%5C%22+vlink%3D%5C%22%23954F72%5C%22+style%3D%5C%22word-wrap%3A+break-word%5C%22%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22mso-fareast-language%3A+EN-US%5C%22%3ECees+%2Cdankjewel%2C%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22mso-fareast-language%3A+EN-US%5C%22%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%26nbsp%3B%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22mso-fareast-language%3A+EN-US%5C%22%3EDonderdag+a.s.+ben+ik+er+wel+en+leuk+om+tegen+Moh+te+oefenen%2C%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22mso-fareast-language%3A+EN-US%5C%22%3EAfgelopen+donderdag+was+erg+goed+om+tegen+AH-Tong+te+hebben+getraind%E2%80%A6..+%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22mso-fareast-language%3A+EN-US%5C%22%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22mso-fareast-language%3A+EN-US%5C%22%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%26nbsp%3B%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22mso-fareast-language%3A+EN-US%5C%22%3EVolgende+week+donderdag+6+juli+ben+ik+verhinderd%3B+dus+dan+niet+inplannen+voor+training+%26nbsp%3B%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22mso-fareast-language%3A+EN-US%5C%22%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%26nbsp%3B%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22mso-fareast-language%3A+EN-US%5C%22%3EGroet%2C+%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22mso-fareast-language%3A+EN-US%5C%22%3EKees+%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22mso-fareast-language%3A+EN-US%5C%22%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%26nbsp%3B%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22mso-fareast-language%3A+EN-US%5C%22%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%26nbsp%3B%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22mso-fareast-language%3A+EN-US%5C%22%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%26nbsp%3B%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cdiv+style%3D%5C%22border%3A+none%3Bborder-top%3A+solid+%23E1E1E1+1.0pt%3Bpadding%3A+3.0pt+0cm+0cm+0cm%5C%22%3E%3Cb%3EVan%3A%3C%2Fb%3E+Cees+van+lastname+%26lt%3Bfaultyaddress%40mywebsite.nl%26gt%3B+%3Cbr%3E%3Cb%3EVerzonden%3A%3C%2Fb%3E+maandag+26+juni+2023+13%3A44%3Cbr%3E%3Cb%3EAan%3A%3C%2Fb%3E+Sport+Overdag+%26lt%3Bfaultyaddress%40mywebsite.nl%26gt%3B%3Cbr%3E%3Cb%3EOnderwerp%3A%3C%2Fb%3E+trainen%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%26nbsp%3B%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22font-size%3A+12.0pt%3Bfont-family%3A+%26quot%3BTahoma%26quot%3B%2Csans-serif%5C%22%3EZie+bijgevoegd+schema.%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22font-size%3A+12.0pt%3Bfont-family%3A+%26quot%3BTahoma%26quot%3B%2Csans-serif%5C%22%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%26nbsp%3B%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22font-size%3A+12.0pt%3Bfont-family%3A+%26quot%3BTahoma%26quot%3B%2Csans-serif%5C%22%3ETot+donderdag.%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22font-size%3A+12.0pt%3Bfont-family%3A+%26quot%3BTahoma%26quot%3B%2Csans-serif%5C%22%3EMet+vriendelijke+groeten%2C%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22font-size%3A+12.0pt%3Bfont-family%3A+%26quot%3BTahoma%26quot%3B%2Csans-serif%5C%22%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%26nbsp%3B%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22font-size%3A+12.0pt%3Bfont-family%3A+%26quot%3BTahoma%26quot%3B%2Csans-serif%5C%22%3ECees+van+lastname%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22font-size%3A+12.0pt%3Bfont-family%3A+%26quot%3BTahoma%26quot%3B%2Csans-serif%5C%22%3ECo%C3%B6rdinator+Sport+Overdag+ttv+MySportclub%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22font-size%3A+12.0pt%3Bfont-family%3A+%26quot%3BTahoma%26quot%3B%2Csans-serif%5C%22%3Email%3A+%3Ca+href%3D%5C%22mailto%3Afaultyaddress%40mywebsite.nl%5C%22+target%3D%5C%22_blank%5C%22+tabindex%3D%5C%22-1%5C%22+rel%3D%5C%22external%5C%22+class%3D%5C%22external%5C%22%3Efaultyaddress%40mywebsite.nl%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22font-size%3A+12.0pt%3Bfont-family%3A+%26quot%3BTahoma%26quot%3B%2Csans-serif%5C%22%3E06-xxxxxxxx%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22font-size%3A+12.0pt%3Bfont-family%3A+%26quot%3BTahoma%26quot%3B%2Csans-serif%5C%22%3Epriv%C3%A9+mail%3A+%3Ca+href%3D%5C%22mailto%3Auser%40personalmail.nl%5C%22+target%3D%5C%22_blank%5C%22+tabindex%3D%5C%22-1%5C%22+rel%3D%5C%22external%5C%22+class%3D%5C%22external%5C%22%3Euser%40personalmail.nl%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22font-size%3A+12.0pt%3Bfont-family%3A+%26quot%3BTahoma%26quot%3B%2Csans-serif%5C%22%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%26nbsp%3B%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22font-size%3A+10.0pt%3Bfont-family%3A+%26quot%3BTahoma%26quot%3B%2Csans-serif%5C%22%3EAls+je+geen+mail+meer+wil+ontvangen+van+SportOverdag+van+ttv+MySportclub%2C+laat+me+dat+dan+even+weten.%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22font-size%3A+12.0pt%3Bfont-family%3A+%26quot%3BTahoma%26quot%3B%2Csans-serif%5C%22%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%5C%22font-size%3A+12.0pt%3Bfont-family%3A+%26quot%3BTahoma%26quot%3B%2Csans-serif%5C%22%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%26nbsp%3B%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3Cbr+%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fblockquote%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%22%2C%22IsHtml%22%3Atrue%2C%22Importance%22%3A3%2C%22SendReadingConfirmation%22%3Afalse%2C%22Attachments%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22InReplyTo%22%3A%22%3C000201d9a829%24ad56e960%240804bc20%24%40personalmail.nl%3E%22%2C%22References%22%3A%22%3C4bdda8120d59524b9456c25f482efcce%40mail.mywebsite.nl%3E+%3C000201d9a829%24ad56e960%240804bc20%24%40personalmail.nl%3E%22%2C%22Sensitivity%22%3A0%2C%22Method%22%3A%22SendMessage%22%2C%22ShowReport%22%3Atrue%2C%22SentFolder%22%3A%22INBOX.Sent%22%7D&TenantName=Default
--554ba553-F--
    HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
    Last-Modified: Sun, 12 Mar 2023 15:15:00 GMT
    ETag: "31b-5f6b57545f770"
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Content-Length: 795
    Cache-Control: s-maxage=10
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: text/html
    
    --8f8b2a62-H--
    Message: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "(?i)((?:\\bx(?:link:href|html|mlns)|!ENTITY\\b.*?\\b(?:SYSTEM|PUBLIC)|\\bdata:text\\/html))" at ARGS:Parameters. [file "/etc/apache2/modsecurity.d/rules/comodo_free/07_XSS_XSS.conf"] [line "173"] [id "213060"] [rev "5"] [msg "COMODO WAF: XSS Filter - Category 3: Attribute Vector||mail.mywebsite.nl|F|2"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "CWAF"] [tag "XSS"]
    Apache-Error: [file "apache2_util.c"] [line 271] [level 3] [client 86.xx.xxx.xxx] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "(?i)((?:\\\\\\\\bx(?:link:href|html|mlns)|!ENTITY\\\\\\\\b.*?\\\\\\\\b(?:SYSTEM|PUBLIC)|\\\\\\\\bdata:text\\\\\\\\/html))" at ARGS:Parameters. [file "/etc/apache2/modsecurity.d/rules/comodo_free/07_XSS_XSS.conf"] [line "173"] [id "213060"] [rev "5"] [msg "COMODO WAF: XSS Filter - Category 3: Attribute Vector||mail.mywebsite.nl|F|2"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "CWAF"] [tag "XSS"] [hostname "mail.mywebsite.nl"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "ZJqECGcNX@kM-QmM3hU2ywAAABM"]
    Action: Intercepted (phase 2)
    Stopwatch: 1687847944917965 34695 (- - -)
    Stopwatch2: 1687847944917965 34695; combined=28524, p1=593, p2=27771, p3=0, p4=0, p5=159, sr=124, sw=1, l=0, gc=0
    Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.6 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); CWAF_Apache.
    Server: Apache
    Engine-Mode: "ENABLED"
```

Comment: Could you show the mentioned rule? (`id` 213060 from file `/etc/apache2/modsecurity.d/rules/comodo_free/07_XSS_XSS.conf`)? What is in your audit.log?

Comment: edited the post with ID 213060 from 07_XSS_XSS.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitelisting the client(s) is not a good idea (in much cases).

You should make an exclusion, for eg.:

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@strEq /" \
    "id:1000,\
    phase:1,\
    pass,\
    t:none,\
    nolog,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=213060;ARGS:Parameters"
```

Check the `uri` in this rule (it does not seem in your log), fix it, and put this exclusion rule **BEFORE** the rule above. You can change the operator (`@strEq`) too if you think the mentioned one is not good enough.

This will make an exclusion: if the URI matches, then target `ARGS:Parameters` will be removed in case of rule 213060.

Comment: I fully agree that whitelisting is not a good solution. That's why I'm asking for help here right now instead of putting the ip address on the whitelist again. ;-)
Thank you for your answer, but I still do not understand it. Besides of making an exception, there is a reason thay this happens and I'm trying to figure out what causes it. I'm wondering if having this bypass/exception isn't as 'bad' as putting the ip address on the whitelist?

Comment: I see your problem - perhaps this is what you can find in audit.log (I asked it in my first comment above.)

Comment: edited the main post once again, with part of the audtit.log. Is this sufficient information? I hardly understand what's going on here, so not sure if this is enough.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful indeed. Btw it's very weird: after the transformations the `Parameters` argument will be `{"Accounta lot of bla bla bla bla bla 22INBOX.Drafts"}`, which is definitely **NOT** matches with the given pattern at the rule. I checked it with more tools, and I couldn't reproduce it. What happens if you remove the `ARGS:Parameters` with the exclusion? Can user use that resource?

Comment: I will try to read all that bla bla bla bla that I removed, I thought that might contain some sensible information, so I removed it. I will post that info tomorrow.

Comment: You can send me directly, if you do not want to share those information.

Comment: I've updated the initial post once again; I sanitized the content a bit, I removed last names and email addresses and phone numbers etc, no other adjustsments and this is straigiht from the log file.

Comment: Thanks - well, after unquoting the body and check the regex, there are five matches. It's definitely a false positive. See https://regex101.com/r/eGdWNK/1.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I will implement the exclusion you mentioned in your first answer and I will mark it as accepted! Thanks again for all the research!

Comment: You are welcome - glad to see that I could help you :)